# Why would UPDATE with JOIN queries be so much slower than SELECT with JOIN queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, sql-update

This has been a 19-hour long nightmare.

I have a very large query that in essence needs to join large datasets across a couple tables.  After I make the join, I need to update the original table with the data from the select statement.  The SELECT statement is super fast, and the UPDATE statement is super slow.

This is the select statement.

```
SELECT l.col1,
       l.col2,
       l.col3,
       p.personid
FROM table1 p
LEFT JOIN table2 l ON (l.col1 = p.col1)
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT name,
          col AS 'col2'
   FROM tbl3 f
   WHERE f.col LIKE '%-F') pcf ON (pcf.col1 = p.col1)
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT name,
          col AS 'col3'
   FROM tbl4 f
   WHERE f.col LIKE '%-M') pcm ON (pcm.col1 = p.col1)
WHERE p.requestid = '1928'
```

Now, if I take the EXACT SAME series of JOINs and put it inside an UPDATE context, the query takes forever.

```
UPDATE table1 p
LEFT JOIN table2 l ON (l.col1 = p.col1)
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT name,
          col AS 'col2'
   FROM tbl3 f
   WHERE f.col LIKE '%-F') pcf ON (pcf.col1 = p.col1)
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT name,
          col AS 'col3'
   FROM tbl4 f
   WHERE f.col LIKE '%-M') pcm ON (pcm.col1 = p.col1)
SET p.col1 = l.col1,
    p.col2 = l.col2,
    p.col3 = l.col3
WHERE p.requestid = '1928'
```

So...why would the UPDATE JOIN statement take so much longer than the SELECT JOIN statement?  Oodles of time longer.  And I already tried temporary tables and it didn't work.

FYI, I'm working with tables of 50k records or more.

If you're curious about the EXPLAIN results, this is what happens when I EXPLAIN the select query (although apparently you can't use explain for update?)

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY p   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    613246  Using where
1   PRIMARY l   eq_ref  PRIMARY,name_3,name,name_2  PRIMARY 257 drilldev_db.p.lastname  1   
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    23435   
1   PRIMARY <derived3>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    13610   
1   PRIMARY <derived4>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    13053   
1   PRIMARY <derived5>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    8273    
1   PRIMARY <derived6>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    11481   
1   PRIMARY <derived7>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    6708    
1   PRIMARY <derived8>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    9588    
1   PRIMARY <derived9>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    5494    
1   PRIMARY <derived10> ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    6981    
1   PRIMARY <derived11> ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    4107    
1   PRIMARY <derived12> ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    5973    
1   PRIMARY <derived13> ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3851    
1   PRIMARY <derived14> ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    4935    
1   PRIMARY <derived15> ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3574    
1   PRIMARY <derived16> ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    5793    
1   PRIMARY <derived17> ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    4706    
17  DERIVED f   ref year,gender gender  257     364263  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
16  DERIVED f   ref year,gender gender  257     397322  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
15  DERIVED f   range   year,gender year    4   NULL    54092   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
14  DERIVED f   range   year,gender year    4   NULL    54092   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
13  DERIVED f   range   year,gender year    4   NULL    62494   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
12  DERIVED f   range   year,gender year    4   NULL    62494   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
11  DERIVED f   range   year,gender year    4   NULL    69317   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
10  DERIVED f   range   year,gender year    4   NULL    69317   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
9   DERIVED f   ref year,gender gender  257     364263  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
8   DERIVED f   range   year,gender year    4   NULL    94949   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
7   DERIVED f   ref year,gender gender  257     364263  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
6   DERIVED f   ref year,gender gender  257     397322  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
5   DERIVED f   ref year,gender gender  257     364263  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
4   DERIVED f   ref year,gender gender  257     397322  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
3   DERIVED f   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    37045   Using where
2   DERIVED f   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    37045   Using where
```

Thanks!

-b

Comment: can you use the command "explain" and post the output

Comment: How are you measuring the "super fast" for the `select`?  Is it time to the first result or time for all the results?  You can check by adding something like `order by col1 limit 1` to see how long that takes (all the results need to be generated for the `order by`).

Comment: Why do you have all those JOINs? Since they're LEFT JOIN, they don't restrict the matched rows in the original table.

Comment: I added the explain statement @jcho360

Comment: Are there any indexes or (update) trigger on the table being modified?

Comment: @alzaimar what's an update trigger?  There are indexes on all the relevant columns.

Comment: an 'update trigger' does actions whenever an UPDATE is executed on a table. I don't know whether MySQL supports triggers, though. Anyway, the rebuild of an index takes some time and if you have a lot of indexes and a large table, such an update just needs quite a bit of time to execute.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your actual statement you don't need the 2nd and 3rd LEFT JOIN as they will not change the result.

Btw, MySQL is not known to process "complex" queries efficiently :-)
If you materialize the result of the SELECT in a temporary table and use this instead it shoul dbe much faster.

Comment: I do have a temporary table version that I thought would work faster but it's still falling short :(.  The UPDATE query is just super intensive.

Comment: Then you should show the table DDLs, there must be something wrong. How many rows are returned by the SELECT?

Comment: What are table DDLs? SELECT returns the same # of rows as the original table I'm trying to match (5k when it starts to break)

Comment: DDL is Data Definition Language, i.e. the CREATE TABLE statements. WHERE p.requestid = '1928' sounds like a quite restrictive condition to me, 5000 rows is a lot, but still not enough to run for hours. Same for index maintenance, it's additional overhead.

Answer (score -1):

Let's think about this for a minute. If you are selecting rows of a table (just grabbing them) versus updating every...single....row as you go through them, what would take longer? Reading n number of lines or modifying (updating) n number of lines?

Compare it to reading 10 lines of a book versus writing the same 10 lines on a sheet of paper. Which one takes longer?

May I also add that, the more rows you are reading vs updating, the bigger the difference will be. Just as there would be more of a difference in reading vs writing lines of a book, the more lines you were reading/writing.

Comment: I understand why it would take longer.  I guess I'm more interested in finding out why it takes *so* much longer (and if I'm doing something way inefficient that I can fix).  Thanks.